# Redshift: How to pin my queries in the Redshift console?

Tags: amazon-redshift

recently I am using Amazon Redshift in my job. I need to look into Redshift console to analyse my query performance, but I have seen that the Redshift console has the limit in showing only the last 100 executed queries. In my company there are a lot of people that launch queries on our Redshift cluster and I am not able to look at my query performances.

Is there something that can prioritize my query? In practice, I am looking for something that can pin my query in the Redshift console in order to analyse its performances.

Thanks a lot!